# Generating embedded charts via qt activex

Tags: excel, qt, charts, activex, ole

I've found a code for inserting a chart type worksheet (not embedded charts) in excel using Qt Activex as below:

The code works fine. I'm wondering where can if find the standards APIs/some examples for dealing with charts specially with embedded charts. Where can I find some example or APIs for dealing with embedded charts in excel via qt Activex.

I'll be very appreciated if anyone can guide me through generating embedded excel charts with QActivex

```
    QAxObject *excel = new QAxObject("Excel.Application", 0);
QAxObject *workbook = excel->querySubObject("Workbooks")->querySubObject("Add");
QAxObject *worksheet = workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(1)");
worksheet->setProperty("Name", "Dati applicazione");
worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(1,1)")->dynamicCall("SetValue", "Serie");
worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(1,2)")->dynamicCall("SetValue", "Dati");

QAxObject *cell;
double dval;
for (int i = 2; i < 10; ++i) {
    dval = qrand();
    cell = worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", i, 1);
    cell->dynamicCall("SetValue(int)", i-1);
    cell = worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", i, 2);
    cell->dynamicCall("SetValue(double)", dval);
    cell = worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)",i,3);
    cell->dynamicCall("SetValue(double)", dval/2.0);
    cell = worksheet->querySubObject("Cells(int,int)", i, 4);
    cell->dynamicCall("SetValue(double)", dval/3.0);
}

QAxObject *range = worksheet->querySubObject("Range(A2:C9)");
range->dynamicCall("Select(void)");

QAxObject *chart = workbook->querySubObject("Charts")->querySubObject("Add");
chart->setProperty("Name", "Report Grafico dei dati");
chart->setProperty("Chart Type", 73);

QAxObject *series = chart->querySubObject("SeriesCollection");

QAxObject *serie = series->querySubObject("Item (int)", 1);
QAxObject *xvalues = worksheet->querySubObject("Range(A2:A9)");
QAxObject *yvalues = worksheet->querySubObject("Range(B2:B9)");
serie->setProperty("XValues", xvalues->asVariant());
serie->setProperty("Values", yvalues->asVariant());

serie = series->querySubObject("Item (int)", 2);
yvalues = worksheet->querySubObject("Range(C2:C9)");
serie->setProperty("XValues", xvalues->asVariant());
serie->setProperty("Values", yvalues->asVariant());

serie = series->querySubObject("Item (int)",3);
yvalues = worksheet->querySubObject("Range(D2:D9)");
serie->setProperty("XValues", xvalues->asVariant());
serie->setProperty("Values", yvalues->asVariant());

workbook->dynamicCall("SaveAs(const QString&)", "E:\\test\\test.xls");
workbook->dynamicCall("Close (Bollean)", false);
excel->dynamicCall("Quit (void)");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Hope to this code works:

```
QAxObject* test = workbook->querySubObject("ActiveSheet");
QAxObject* charts = test->querySubObject("ChartObjects");
QList<QVariant> f; f << 200 << 400 << 200 << 200;
QVariant ch = charts->dynamicCall("Add(int, int, int, int)", f );
```

But unfortunately it gives this error and I have no idea why

```
QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member ChartObjects: Member not found
```

Edit: I've changed the second line to below and it worked
test->querySubObject("ChartObjects()");

Comment: It may be that you have no ActiveSheet. That can happen when the application is not visible. Try getting workbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(1)") like in the previous example. The worksheets support ChartObjects.

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro That doesn't make any difference. I've already tried that

Comment: Hmm. May be the type. ChartObjects is a collection and you are trying to assign to an object pointer. In the example, they don't deal with collections but assign the add directly, with QAxObject *chart = workbook->querySubObject("Charts")->querySubObject("Add")

Comment: @CarlosE.Ferro this : workbook->querySubObject("Charts")->querySubObject("Add") add a worksheet chart whereas I want embedded chart

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the dynamic call to add below. Good to hear that you got it finally working.